# select2: control how many options to show

Tags: jquery

I have a select box that shows about 7 options. How can I make `select2` show more options?

```
<td class="span4"><select id="tec" class="span4"><option></option>
    <option>A1</option><option>A2</option><option>C1</option>
    <option>C2</option><option>C3</option><option>E1</option>
    <option>E2</option><option>G1</option><option>G2</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

**It's about showing more choices, not about selecting**

Comment: First you should close your select tag...

Comment: [`<select id="tec" class="span4" multiple="multiple">`](http://jsfiddle.net/hxfBZ/3/) with `ctrl+click`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked:

html:

```
<select class="bigdrop">
```

jquery:

```
$(".bigdrop .select2-results").css("max-height","400px");
```

Comment: With the new select2 - version 4, the `max-height` is set to an inner element with class `.select2-results__options`, so should be replaced.

Comment: PS: Looking into the select2 plugin CSS file, another approach could be with css selectior:
`.select2-container--bootstrap .select2-results > .select2-results__options` { max-height: 400px; }

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to just display more options than the default without it looking bad, I just wrote a jQuery plugin ([maximize-select2-height](https://github.com/panorama-ed/maximize-select2-height)) to do exactly this. See the screenshots on the GitHub page (linked) to see how it behaves under different page layout circumstances.

Hope that's helpful to someone!

Comment: (Note that this plugin is built for Select2 v4.x.x only.)

Comment: Great little plugin, this should be a standard option in Select2.  Thanks @JacobEvelyn

Answer (score 3):

All select2 containers can be set the same height.

I just added this style, it's working for me

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Select2 elements in your page, you might want to have different maximum item limitations per Select2 element.

I wrote a *Less.js* implementation where you can generate how many items you want to list as css classes

**Note:** You should check out the font for the base height of an item in the dropdown menu. In this example 36px is used as the heigth of one item in the dropdown list.

```
.generate-s2-maxheight(@n:6, @base-height:36px, @i:1) when (@i < @n) {
    
    .select2-container--default .s2-mh-@{i} .select2-results>.select2-results__options 
    {
        max-height: (@base-height * @i) !important;
    }

    // Iterate to the next css generation until it reaches to @n
    .generate-s2-maxheight(@n, @base-height, (@i+1));
}
    
// Generation of css classes for item limitation from 1 to 9 items (10 is excluded)
//
.generate-s2-maxheight(10);
```

Example CSS to show 5 items in dropdown:

```
    .select2-container--default .s2-mh-5 .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
        max-height: 180px !important;
    }
```

---

As result you can use the configuration `dropdownCssClass` to pass the css class

```
 $("<SELECT2_CLASS_OR_ID>").select2({
     dropdownCssClass: "s2-mh-<NUM_OF_ITEMS_TO_SHOW>"
 });
```

Example:

```
 $(".select2").select2({
     dropdownCssClass: "s2-mh-5"
 });
`
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding multiple and size attribute

```
<td class="span4">
    <select id="tec" class="span4" size="10" multiple="multiple">
       <option></option>
       <option>A1</option><option>A2</option><option>C1</option>
       <option>C2</option><option>C3</option><option>E1</option>
      <option>E2</option><option>G1</option><option>G2</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: `size` did not affect __select2__.